# Chrome Incognito mode & Gmail Login

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, private-browsing

If I open Chrome in Ingognito mode & login to a Gmail account & then open a second incognito window how does Gmail automatically log in into the same account?

i.e. What lets Gmail figure what account to log in to if I'm already logging in from an incognito window? Aren't cookies etc blocked?

Comment: Cookies are not blocked while in Incognitio.  They are simply not kept when the Incognitio session is closed.  Incognitio is not actually a privacy mode, you can still be tracked, same as always.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome's "Clear Browsing Data" does not clear cookies for open incognito tabs?](http://superuser.com/questions/690511/chromes-clear-browsing-data-does-not-clear-cookies-for-open-incognito-tabs)

Answer (score 4):

Incognito mode doesn't store browsing records once you're done, but while it is active it is still a browser with cookies etc. Cookies are stored while you're in incognito mode, but are flushed once you exit, along with your incognito browsing history.

Comment: Thanks. That explains a lot. Only one question: How come in my non-incognito Chrome Window I can stay logged in to a different Gmail account? Are all cookies shared between all incognito windows but separately from non-incognito windows?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @curious_cat - You could log into multiple Google Accounts, in a  incognito session if you so desired, I do it all the time

Comment: @Ramhound Simultanously? How? i.e. Incognito Window#1 has Account-A logged in and Incognito Window #2 has account B logged in &  I can switch between the two?

Comment: I routinly log into multiple Google Accounts while using Chrome in Incognito mode.  [I just add a tab to the same session.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TLwrP.png)